# Java development kit 1.7 and earlier version compatibility

Tags: java

I am currently working on `java 1.7` standard version, and I am really fun of the new features:

- `Nio`(new input out put)
- non redundant code with collections
- ...

I want to know if there is a way to switch the class I want to execute depending on the version of `(JRE)java runtime environment` it will be deployed.

Comment: You haven't exactly asked a question. Are your wanting to know if there's a way to determine the JRE version during execution and then use certain features based on that?

Comment: Exactly! this is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to create some sort of launcher app in order to check the JRE version of the environment, then you can lauch the JAR compiled for those version of the JRE. Your code cannot be compiled to newer versions of the JRE and be executed in an older one. That's why you need to complie the launcher app targeting a very old JRE.

As a side note, you can obtain the JRE version in which your program is running using:

```
System.getProperty("java.version")
```

Comment: that's right. Any link I can use to have more details?

Comment: Suppose you have two JARs, one compiled targeting Java 6 (MyApp6.jar) and the other one targeting Java 7 (MyApp7.jar). In your launcher app (Launcher.jar) compiled targeting Java 6 (or the lowest JRE version you wish to support) you can detect the System JRE version using something like:

public static void main(String[] args) {
String jarName;
if(System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.6")) {
jarName = "MyApp6.jar";
}
if(System.getProperty("java.version").startsWith("1.7")) {
jarName = "MyApp7.jar";
}
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar " + jarName);
}

Comment: i Will looks into it.

Answer (score 2):

The Java class file(s) are almost always binary compatible with new versions of the language (and the few exceptions, like using `enum` before the keyword was added, are fairly rare). If you restrict your usage of features to the "lowest common denominator" it is possible to compile back to an arbitrary version. That being said, Java 7 is now quite long in the tooth and I've found Java 8 to be remarkably stable. Finally, if you do choose to use new language features (like lambdas) you cannot use the earlier version of the language.

Comment: I would like to compile two classes for both versions, then depending on the environment recognize it is either 1.8, 1.7 or earlier and select with class I can execute instead.

Comment: @JeanWilliamEyidi Why? Just compile to 1.7 (or 1.6), and then it can it run in 1.6 (and/or 1.7) and/or 1.8. Your way you have to create a separate version for each language iteration, and then you have to support them. Basically, you **don't** want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two compiled build for both version to use language feature differently and have them running on jre 7, but you should just upgrade code compatibility and runtime  to 1.8 (Even better)

Comment: ok I guess that's a start but how do I **switch** it depending on the **environment**?

Comment: in development manually, in runtime environment jre 7 can take code compiled on 1.6 jdk